# How to get both result in composed future in scala

Tags: scala, future

I have two functions

```
f1() => Future[T] 
f2(t: T) => Future[T1]
```

I can get T1 by

```
f1().flatMap(t => f2(t))
```

But I want to get both T and T1, for example (T, T1), how can I do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map the result of f2 inside the flatMap:

```scala
f1().flatMap(t => f2(t).map((t, _)))
```

Or using for-comprehension:

```scala
for {
  t <- f1()
  t1 <- f2(t)
} yield (t, t1)
```

Alternatively, you can zip two futures to one that returns a tuple:

```scala
val a = f1()
val b = a.flatMap(f2)
val c = a zip b
```